# Замена элементов на произведение индексов многомерного массива

Tags: python, массивы, замена

1.)Напишите программу формирования массива размером 5*5
с помощью датчика случайных чисел. Замените в нем все элементы,
значения которых кратны трем, на соответствующие произведения их
индексов. Выведите на экран исходный и измененный массив. 2.)Составьте программу формирования и вывод на экран одномерного массива, состоящего из сумм элементов строк двумерного массива,заданного с помощью датчика случайных, уменьшенных в пять раз.

```
import random
a = []
n = 5
m = 5
for i in range(n):
    b = []
    for j in range(m):
       b.append(int(random.randint(1,100)))
    a.append(b)
print(a)
```

Comment: Сделал все что пришло в голову, numpy использовать запрещено (

Comment: Показывайте, что пришло в голову

Comment: НЕ КАРТИНКОЙ, а код.

Comment: Правил вопрос,см фото;)

Comment: Простите,с телефона сижу

Comment: Ну ладно, заполнили. Теперь дословно выполняйте `Замените в нем все элементы, значения которых кратны трем, на соответствующие произведения их индексов` - какие здесь есть проблемы?

Comment: Проблема в том что я совсем зеленый и даже for составить не могу для перебора чисел и последующей замены

Comment: Точно такие же вложенные фор, как у вас есть

Comment: Хорошо,пойду дальше колотить пустую голову)

Answer (score 0):

```
c = []
for i in range(n):
    b = []
    for j in range(m):
       if a[i][j]%3:
          b.append(a[i][j])
       else:
          b.append(i*j)
    c.append(b)
```